# Printing the value of an combination of one, two, and three dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, php-5.3

I have this combination of multi-dimensional array but I can't print the correct value out on the screen,

```
$parent = array(
    array(
        'function_name' => 'home',
        'screen_name' => 'Home'
        ),

    array(
        'function_name' => 'categories',
        'screen_name' => 'Categories',


        array(
            'function_name' => 'post',
            'screen_name' => 'Post',
            )
        ),

    array(
        'function_name' => 'pages',
        'screen_name' => 'Pages',


        array(
            'function_name' => 'add',
            'screen_name' => 'Add',

            array(
                'function_name' => 'manage',
                'screen_name' => 'Manage'
                )
            )
        )
);
```

some arrays are by themselves, some are with **sub** arrays, and some sub arrays have **subsub** arrays.

```
foreach($parent as $index => $item)
{   
    echo 'parent - '.$item['screen_name'].'<br/>';

    foreach($item as $child)
    {
        echo 'child - '.$child['screen_name'].'<br/>';

        foreach($child as $grandchild)
        {
            echo 'grandchild - '.$grandchild['screen_name'].'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

error message,

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in -> foreach($child as $grandchild)
```

the result I am looking for is like this,

```
parent - Home
parent - Categories
  child - Post
parent - Pages
  child - Add
     grandchild - Manage
```

**EDIT:**

I tried with this test below,

```
foreach ($system as $inner_1) {

    if (is_array($inner_1)) 
    {

        foreach ($inner_1 as $inner_2) 
        {

             if (is_array($inner_2)) 
             {
                  foreach ($inner_2 as $inner_3) 
                  {
                     var_dump($inner_3['function_name']);
                  }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get a strange result,

```
string 'p' (length=1) // don't know why I get this.
string 'P' (length=1) // don't know why I get this.

string 'a' (length=1) // don't know why I get this.
string 'A' (length=1) // don't know why I get this.

string 'manage' (length=6) // correct result.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `foreach($item as $child)` on `$parent[1]`, `$child` takes the following values: `'home'`, `'Home'` and an array.

What about keeping the arrays purely associative?

```
$parent = array(
    array(
        'function_name' => 'categories',
        'screen_name' => 'Categories',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'function_name' => 'post',
                'screen_name' => 'Post'
            ),
            array(
                'function_name' => 'review',
                'screen_name' => 'Review',
                'children' => array(
                    ...
                )
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

This way you can run `foreach ($item['children'] as $child)` knowing the argument is an array (you need to make sure that `$item['children']` exists and is an array).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but a parent usually has more than one child, will this work?